# Slow custom menu save

Tags: wordpress

I have a very large custom menu (~200 items)
Once i try to save the menu it just goes on loading forever (over 15 minutes now).

I am pretty sure it shouldn't be like this and of course cannot work like this.

what can i do to solve this .

I have tried increasing php limits (memory/timeout) but im not sure it is relevant.

As i read on some article there is a heavy process that goes on that can be unhooked , 
but i couldn't find how it is done.

There is no error ,it just keeps on going.

Im using word press 3.5 BTW

Comment: well ,this is not the question , and it is the customer's decision so no choice , 200 items shouldn't make WordPress break should it ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) would be a better option?